# Selecting K with elbow method for K-modes (binary or nominal data)

Tags: clustering, variance, binary-data, k-means, categorical-data

I have run the k-modes algorithm on my nominal data set, which I converted to a dummy matrix (binary). As for K-Means, one can perform the elbow method by looking at the elbow method using, according to Wikipedia, the ***Percentage of variance explained is the ratio of the between-group variance to the total variance, also known as an F-test*** [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)).

How would one compute the `between-group variance ratio` or simply the `SS(W)` for a nominal/binary data set? Are there available approaches?

Thanks for any help and insights!

PS: I have already performed the silhouette score using jaccard index or dice from the using scipy library and would like to compute the elbow method as well.

Comment: Variance is for continuous variables, not nominal data.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Hence my question. Is there a comparable approach for nominal data? I have encountered `Unalikeability` (Kader et al 2007; http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v15n2/kader.pdf) but I am unsure if one could employ it in a similar fashion

Comment: Well, many distance-based methods like Silhouette can still be used if you have a distance function. But that doesn't mean they will be very reliable, but mostly can serve as a first guess. Some of these will require you finding an "elbow" too...

Comment: Refer to the below link might be of some help.
https://www.kaggle.com/ashydv/bank-customer-clustering-k-modes-clustering/comments